# Joining two tables then calculating the time difference between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about a SQL query. I have two tables that I would like to compare information from. An artists table and an events table.

I have created this query to join the tables. And get the two times I am looking at.

```
SELECT  id_artist, full_name, event_title, events.created_at, mobile_number, email, users.created_at
FROM events   
JOIN users
  ON users.id_user = events.id_user
group by id_artist;
```

Is there a way to compare these two .created_at fields to see only show rows where the difference between artist creation and event creation is 3 days?

| id_artist | events.created_at | users.created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-08-28 09:58:23 | 2019-08-29 06:35:38 |
| 2 | 2019-09-07 20:36:24 | 2019-09-13 21:29:00 |
| 3 | 2019-10-16 21:57:34 | 2019-10-16 22:12:13 |
| 4 | 2019-10-17 15:41:37 | 2019-10-17 15:38:27 |

Here is an example of what the data looks like. I would like there to be one more column that has the time difference in days. Then I could query this column for results greater than 3 days.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid and will raise an error in newer MySQL versions. (Unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh I just added an example table. I would like there to be one more column that has the time difference in days. Then I could query this column for results greater than 3 days.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
    SELECT  id_artist, full_name, event_title,
    events.created_at, mobile_number, email, users.created_at
    FROM events   
    JOIN users
      ON users.id_user = events.id_user
    WHERE users.created_at = DATE_ADD(events.created_at, INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
    group by id_artist;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this query ->

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM events 
JOIN artists ON events.id_user = artists.id_use
WHERE datediff(day,artists.created_at,events.created_at) = 3
```

Comment: This is the message that I am recieving: "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'"